# Clarification on integer constant expressions

Tags: c, c99

Somewhere I've read that integer constant expressions consists integer constants such as:

```
(5 + 5) //integer constant expression
```

That was the only example I have seen.

Now, from standard which says:

> (C99 6.6/6) An integer constant expression shall have integer type
>   and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration
>   constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are
>   integer constants, and floating constants that are the immediate
>   operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression
>   shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part
>   of an operand to the sizeof operator.

So, are all these integer expressions below if I'm right?

```
int i; float f = 3.14f;

i = 42;
i = f;
i = (int)(5/3.14f);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(int)(5/3.14f)` is not an integer constant expression.

You are using a floating constant that is not an *immediate operands of cast*.

And of course in `i = f;` the object `f` is not an integer constant expression.

Comment: Are you sure? `(5/3.14f)` is a floating constexpr in itself. Both GCC and clang lets me compile `const int x = (int)(5/3.14f);` with `-Wall -ansi -std=c89 -pedantic`.

Comment: @H2CO3: `(5/3.14f)` is an arithmetic constant expression, not a floating constant. The whole expression is still an arithmetic constant expression, but (by §6.6) not an integer constant expression.

Comment: @H2CO3 try to compile with this expression `sizeof (struct { int a:((int) (5/3.14f));})` and you'll get the desired warning.

Comment: Can you please include an example of what do you mean by _immediate operands of cast_?

Comment: @user963241: `(int)(3.14f)`. The cast has to be applied to the constant, not to a composite constant expression.

Comment: How can `i = 42;` be an integer constant expression since `i` is a variable and not a constant?

Comment: @user963241 `i = 42;` is a statement (notice the `;`), not an expression. Now `42` is an integer constant expression but `i = 42` is not an integer constant expression.

Comment: whether long and long long are also considered as integer constants in C in addition to char, integer etc