# Can a null pointer constant be any integer constant expression evaluated to 0?

Tags: c, pointers, null, language-lawyer, constant-expression

The standard says:

> "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type **`void*`**, is called a *null pointer constant*.67) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."
>
> ---
>
> "*67) The macro NULL is defined in stddef.h (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.*"
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.2.3.2/3 "Pointers".

The most common *null pointer constants* are of course, `0` and `(void*) 0` used by most implementations as *null pointer constant*, but as the standard mandates - *"**An integer constant expression with the value 0**, or such an expression cast to type `void*`*" - a *null pointer constant* shall also be any of the following:

1. `1 * 0`
2. `0 * 0`
3. `0 - 0`
4. `25 - 25`
5. `(-4) + (4)`
6. `(0 * ((0 * 25) * 3)`
7. `(0) * (-100)`

Like any of their pendants preceded by `(void*)`, f.e. `(void*) (1 * 0)` or `(void*) (25 - 25)`.

As well as boolean expressions:

8. `(void*) ((1 + 1) == 25)`
9. `(void*) !(9)`

---

Thus, any statement like one of these:

1. `int* ptr = 25 - 25;`
2. `int* ptr = (void*) ((-4) + 4);`
3. `int* ptr = (0 * ((0 * 25) * 3);`
4. `int* ptr = (void*) !(9);`
5. `int* ptr = ((1 + 1) == 25);`

shall make `ptr`, per standard, a *null pointer*.

---

- Am I correct or is there anything wrong about my concerns?

I am looking for any part of the C standard which invalidates this thesis.

As far as I searched, there shouldn´t be a duplicate of this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not sure the standard guarantee that `25 - 25` is a constant.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14081737/4386278

Comment: @EugeneSh. Isn´t it an integer constant expression?

Comment: I don't see why these wouldn't work.  Note that your question *title* ("Can ... any expression evaluated to 0") is different and is *not* true.  For example, `(void*) strlen("")` would not be guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6 - It looks like the necessary conditions are listed, but not the sufficient ones. So I am not sure an expression can be guaranteed to be constant.

Comment: @jamesdlin Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that all of these are valid.

Section 6.6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> *1*
>
> ```
> constant-expression:
>     conditional-expression
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *3* Constant  expressions  shall  not  contain  assignment,  increment,  decrement,  function-call,or  comma  operators,  except  when  they are  contained  within  a  subexpression  that  is  not evaluated.
>
> ...
>
> *6* An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and 
>   shall  only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants,
>   enumeration   constants,   character   constants, `sizeof` expressions
>   whose  results  are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and 
>   floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast
>   operators in an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert 
>   arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an
>   operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

Each of the expressions in your examples fit this description, i.e.:

- All operands are integer constants
- The expression is a *conditional-expression* (i.e. doesn't use assignment or comma operators) with no increment, decrement, or function call operators
- Evaluates to 0

So all are valid ways to assign `NULL` to a pointer.

Some examples that are **not** integer constant expressions:

```
int x = 1;
int *ptr1 = (3, 0);    //  invalid, comma operator not allowed
int *ptr2 = (x = 0);   //  invalid, assignment not allowed
int *ptr3 = x - 1;     //  invalid, an operand is not an integer constant
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep.

> `[C99 6.6/6]:` An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof operator.

Note that this is not the case in C++, where null pointer constants are defined differently:

> [`[conv.ptr]/1:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1) A null pointer constant is an integer literal ([lex.icon]) with value zero or a *prvalue* of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`. *[..]*

Comment: The conclusion should be stated

Comment: @EugeneSh. The conclusion is in the first line.